# SQL sorting and adding?

Tags: php, html, sql

So I have been fumbling around with this and I feel like I am missing something.  basically I have a table filled with user information.  The two fields I am concerned about are date and payment.  Basically I am trying to print out a format like:

```
Year: total year income
   Month: total month income
   Month: total month income
   ect.
 Year: total year income
   Month: total month income
   Month: total month income
   ect.
```

Not each year will have entries in every month.  I seem to be having issues getting the date value to correctly display.I tried using this so far but it does not display the months properly, years are fine:

```
if ($results > 0){
  while($info = mysql_fetch_array($alist)) {
    if(substr($info['begin_date'],0,4) > $year){
      $year = substr($info['begin_date'],0,4);
      echo $year . "</br>";
      $month = substr($info['begin_date'],5,2);
      echo $month . "</br>";
    }
    if(substr($info['begin_date'],5,2) > $month){
      $month = substr($info['begin_date'],5,2);
      echo $month . "</br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not that it'd have anything to do with the actual problem, but either way, don't use `mysql_` functions. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: You fail to mention how it does not display the months properly.

Comment: If you want to display several months, you probably need to make a loop. But without knowing the contents of your database, or the SQL query you performed to get the results, there's no real way to help you.

Comment: the mysql_ is something I pulled off of this site actually but ill look into that once it is functioning thanks.

Comment: This is the current output and the first years months are correct but the others are not displaying the right months.
2007
01
02
03
06
07
08
11
12
2008
03
12
2009
01
10
11
12
2010
02
08
09
11
12
2011
01
07
08
2012
07
08
10
12

Comment: those should be vertical but they get flattened out here

Answer (score 0):

```
Select year (date) as pyear, month (date) as pmonth, sum (payment)
From table 
Group by pyear,pmonth
```

This help you to get payments by year and month then put in array to print as you like

Comment: well the problem is that the date is stored in a "yyyy-mm-dd" format.  So I dont believe that query would work.

Comment: It can please use `convert(smalldatetime,date_field,103)`

Comment: @robby fyi it is much better to solve your data problems at sql server side; it will be much faster for the bigdata for small amount of data you may try programatical solutions

Answer (score 0):

This should give payments for each year/month:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) as year
    , MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) as month
    , SUM (income)
FROM table 
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers above has shown how you can extract year and month from date data type in MySQL, which is a valid solution.

Another option will be to use PHP's rich library of date format functions to simplify your code which can be found here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

E.g $year = substr($info['begin_date'],0,4); becomes
$year = date('Y', strtotime($info['begin_date']) ;